# Why won't my anonymous function fire on grid.prerender?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, objectdatasource, anonymous-methods

In my gridview I have fields for inserting a new record in the footer.

In my objectdatasource selecting event if no records came back I bind a single mock row to force the footer to show so they can still add records. Since the row does not contain real data I hide the row.

```
    ...
    If result.ItemCount = 0 Then
        result = mockRow
        AddHandler mygridview.PreRender, AddressOf HideRow
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HideRow(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
    mygridview.Rows(0).Visible = False
End Sub
```

This works fine. However, I'd like to condense it like this:

```
    ...
    If result.ItemCount = 0 Then
        result = mockRow
        AddHandler mygridview.PreRender, Function() mygridview.Rows(0).Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This compiles fine, but the row doesn't get hidden. Can anyone tell me why my anonymous function isn't getting hit?

Comment: Consider using the Listview control. It renders an insert column for you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515103.aspx

Scroll to bottom to see figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a function that returns a boolean instead of assigning a value.  If you are using VB 2008 you're stuck, but with VB 2010, you could do a sub instead.

```
AddHandler mygridview.PreRender, Sub() mygridview.Rows(0).Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0):

don't you need to add the parameters?

```
AddHandler mygridview.PreRender, _ 
   Function(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) mygridview.Rows(0).Visible = False
```

Comment: It must be able to infer them. I tried it both ways. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
AddHandler mygridview.PreRender, Sub(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) mygridview.Rows(0).Visible = False
```

So, you were both half right.